# Fastest way to find and edit values in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Imagine I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{'artifactID': 8047.0,
  'memberID': 1,
  'resource_launch': {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'},
 {'artifactID': 8301.0,
  'memberID': 1,
  'resource_launch': {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'},
 {'artifactID': 8374.0,
  'memberID': 1,
  'resource_launch': {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'},
 {'artifactID': 8641.0,
  'memberID': 1,
  'resource_launch': {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'},
 {'artifactID': 8969.0,
  'memberID': 1,
  'resource_launch': {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}
]
```

This list has over a Million dictionaries. I would like to find `memberID` and `artifactID` combinations, and if the combination exists, add some values to existing keys under the `resource_launch` dictionary.

For example: If I look for the combination of `artifactID=8969` and `memberID=1`, I would like that record updated within the list of dictionaries as follows:

```
[{'artifactID': 8047.0,
  'memberID': 1,
  'resource_launch': {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'},
 {'artifactID': 8301.0,
  'memberID': 1,
  'resource_launch': {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'},
 {'artifactID': 8374.0,
  'memberID': 1,
  'resource_launch': {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'},
 {'artifactID': 8641.0,
  'memberID': 1,
  'resource_launch': {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'},
 {'artifactID': 8969.0,
  'memberID': 1,
  'resource_launch': {'key1':['value1','value4'],'key2':['value2','value5'],'key3':['value3','value6']}
]
```

If the combination doesn't exist, I'd like to add that to the list of dictionaries.

How do I achieve it in a fast way, given that this list will contain well over a Million dictionaries? Right now, I'm just adding every record, without checking if the record exists, and that's taking a very long amount of time.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Here's my starter code which is taking too long and doesn't achieve what I want:

```
finalJSON = []
for memberID in tqdm(artifactsTimespent['memberID'].unique()):
    temp_artifactsTimespent = artifactsTimespent[artifactsTimespent.memberID==memberID]
    for artifactID in temp_artifactsTimespent['artifactID'].unique():
        temp_artifactsTimespent = temp_artifactsTimespent[temp_artifactsTimespent.artifactID==artifactID]

        temp_resourceLaunchData = resourceLaunchData[resourceLaunchData.member_id==memberID]
        temp_resourceLaunchData = temp_resourceLaunchData[temp_resourceLaunchData.artifact_id==artifactID]

        temp_artifactsContentData = artifactsContentData[artifactsContentData.member_id==memberID]
        temp_artifactsContentData = temp_artifactsContentData[temp_artifactsContentData.artifact_id==artifactID]

        temp_artifactRevisions = artifactRevisions[artifactRevisions.artifactid==artifactID]

        memberArtifactData = {}
        memberArtifactData['memberID'] = memberID
        memberArtifactData['artifactID'] = artifactID

        memberArtifactData['resource_launch'] = temp_artifactsContentData['content_data']
        finalJSON.append(memberArtifactData)
```

Comment: Are `artifactID`'s in sorted manner?

Comment: @Ch3steR they're not right now. But I guess I can sort the dataframes before starting to work on them.

Comment: Sounds like `artifactID` and `memberID` together form a primary key on your set of records.  You should try storing your records as a dictionary where the key is a tuple (or frozen `dataclass` or whatever) of `artifactID` and `memberID`.  Though it's possible that this will take a long time even after optimization.